# app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" not works

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to add show/hide password button, i tried to set app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" but unfortunately it doesn't works

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/uPassword"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:autofillHints="user name"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:text="@={authViewModel.password}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uUserName"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/teal_700" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the `EditText` into a `TextInputLayout` like this:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/uPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The password toggle should be visible, though the layout of your `EditText` will look different - like this:

[image: EditText with passoword toggle]